# JPopupMenu disappears on mouseEntered

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jpopupmenu

I have next structure: `JPopupMenu` contains `JPanel` which contains `JMenuItems`. The problem is, I cannot use it because `JPopupMenu` disappears when `mouse enters` to any `menu item`.

**SSCCE:**

```
public class PopupTest {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));

        panel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
                    final JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
                    JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();
                    menuPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
                    menuPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(menuPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(String.valueOf(i));
                        menuPanel.add(item);
                    }

                    menu.add(menuPanel);
                    menu.show(panel, e.getX(), e.getY());
                }
            }
        });
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setBackground(new Color(50, 50, 50, 200));

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

BTW, problem does not repeats when there is no `JPanel` between `JPopupMenu` and its items.

Does anyone know how to prevent that?

Comment: sure, don't use the panel ;-) Or if you think you need it: describe the requirements that forces you. MenuItems that don't reside in a hierarchy of menus are problematic, as you experience. An alternative to not using the intermediate panel, don't use menu/items in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly answering your question but I think, you are unnecessarily adding a `panel` with box layout to `JPopupMenu` when it supports adding `JMenuitem` directly to it. check the following code fragment:

```
                 final JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
                   JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel();
                    menuPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GREEN));
                  //  menuPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(menuPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                             JLabel item = new JLabel(i+"");
                             menuPanel.add(item);
                            }

                    menu.add(menuPanel);

                    menu.show(panel, e.getX(), e.getY());
```

Comment: problem is, i **NEED** to use the `JPanel`

Comment: +1, I agree with Sage, just add the menu items directly to the menu. Why do you think you need to use a JPanel?

Comment: yes i think so too. However @SeniorJD, using JLabel instead of JMenuItem will resolve the issue as i have edited in the answer.

Comment: But i do think you should use JPopupMenu with menuitem. JPopupMenu itself is a component and it has the power laying out it's content as much as any other JComponent.

Comment: I need `JPanel`, because I have to implement complicated structure inside popup.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips:

- Define your pop up menu just once instead every time a button is pressed.
- You need to override `mouseReleased` or `mousePressed` method: [Bringing Up a Popup Menu](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup)
- Use [MouseEvent.isPopupTrigger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#isPopupTrigger%28%29) to find out if pop up should be shown.
- Add `menuItems` directly to `menu` and not to a `JPanel`

**Suggested changes:**

```
    final JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
    menu.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,5)); // How do you can, for example, lay out your menu items horizontally in 2 rows?
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        JMenuItem item = new JMenuItem(String.valueOf(i));
        menu.add(item);
    }

    MouseListener mouseListener = new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if(e.isPopupTrigger()){
                menu.show(panel, e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    };

    panel.addMouseListener(mouseListener);
```

**Picture**

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but...ARE YOU KIDDING ME?? This an SSCCE of that what I NEED to do. Thanks for your care about my code' clean, but I just described what I need. How do you can, for example, lay out your menu items horizontally in 2 rows?

Comment: First of all there's no need to be rude. Second, if you need so why didn't you state that in your question? Third, see updated answer and you'll see you can layout items without using `JPanel`.

Comment: 1. I'm sorry. 2. I've showed that in sscce. 3. ok. and what about 3 columns with separators, labels and different insets?

Comment: @SeniorJD _what I NEED to do_ actually, no .. the SSCCE is about a problem introduced by a perceived solution to a requirement you don't describe.

Comment: I have described it actually.